# Lightbox close event handling

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a simple lightbox on the page, where the close icon has some class `.closeIt`. When user clicks the close icon, I want to shift the focus back to the link element, which triggered the lightbox.

I tried adding some function which takes input of the triggering link and the closing icon class name.

```
 function focusBack(triggeringLinkId,closingLinkClass){
     $(closingLinkClass).click(function () {
        $(triggeringLinkId).focus();
     });
  }
```

and for each lightbox, I manually called the function back like this:

```
 focusBack('#someLink','.closeIt')
```

this approach works fine if I only have one lightbox on the page, but if I have more than one lightboxes, it starts binding it to the last called function, and now whatever lightbox I close, the focus goes back to the triggering link for which I last called the `focusBack` function.

What's the best approach to deal with this kind of situation?

Comment: I don't know if adding or removing a click listener to close button is good idea or not because you may override other click actions on it. However you can use `$(closingLinkClass).off("click")` to remove the click listener after every focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used this work around to solve the problem:

```
function focusBack(triggeringLinkId,closingLinkClass){
$(triggeringLinkId).click(e){
   $(e.target).addClass('triggeringLinkClass');
}
 $(closingLinkClass).click(function () {
    $(triggeringLinkClass).focus();
    $(triggeringLinkClass).removeClass('triggeringLinkClass');
 });
}
```

I don't think that's the best approach, but it resolved the problem for me.